# Autoincrement of Primary Key in SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have added a SQL Server database. I add PK (`bignit`) as primary key. I want to set it to auto increase the no. by 1 as we can do in SSCE database. How is that possible.

Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to make your PK an [Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

in query like this.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.example
(
EgId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

also look for more.
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/03/sql-server-add-or-remove-identity-property-on-column/

Answer (score 0):

```
        int MaxCode = 0;
        DataTable DataTable = new DataTable();

            string sql = "SELECT  isNull(Max(ColumnName),0) AS MaxCode FROM Table
            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlConnection))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
                sqlAdapter.Fill(DataTable);

                if (Convert.ToInt32(DataTable.Rows[0]["MaxCode"]) != 0)
                    MaxCode = Convert.ToInt32(DataTable.Rows[0]["MaxCode"]) + 1;
                else
                    MaxCode = 1;

                sqlAdapter.Dispose();
            }
```